# Response.RedirectToRoute producing exception

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple web forms application. I get the following error:
**Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)**:
Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("etusivu", "opas/{name}", "~/opas/etusivu.aspx");
    }
```

Pageload:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.RedirectToRoute("etusivu", new { name = "etusivu" });

    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What page is that pageload from? What's in the page load for elusive.aspx?

Comment: @BrendaBell This pageload is from the elusive page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question and comments correctly: You're registering a route that redirects to etusive.aspx, the page load in etusive.aspx redirects to that same route and you've created a loop.